# What libraries ship with support for the Java 6 ServiceLoader facility (META-INF/services)?

Tags: java, dependencies, java-6

I'm wondering what adoption rate is of the (now officially supported) [ServiceLoader](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) facility in Java 6. I'd like to begin using it as a preferred way to locate dependencies. Obviously this would be made much easier if the jars already ship with with the necessary configuration file in place.

Just poking around I was happy to see the MySQL JDBC driver has the "META-INF/services" in place (at least in v5.1 of mysql-connector-j).

I'd be interested to know what other major/widely used libraries are known to provide this this.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate, PostgreSQL JDBC to name two.